# Gridster grid with dc.js and d3-tip Not working

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, gridster

I have been trying to put custom tooltip on dc charts and my chart container is gridster grid.

D3-tip Snippet

```
var pieTip = d3.tip()
      .attr("class", "d3-tip")
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return "<span style='color: #f0027f'>" + d.data.key + "</span> : " + numberFormat(d.value);
      });
```

This Snippet is for the rendering.

```
.renderlet(function(chart) {
                chart.select("svg").call(barTip)
                  .selectAll(".bar")
                  .on("mouseover", barTip.show)
                  .on("mouseout", barTip.hide);
```

I couldn't make it work. Any pointers will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The problem is the z-index of the tip when putting the chart inside the modal or a div.

Comment: Oh cool. Thanks for answering - I couldn't see anything wrong with your code but `z-index` is a good thing to keep in mind.

Comment: I just added a rule in css of the model

.model{
 z-index:10001;
}